# Perl: Changing some methods of a module with use parent

Tags: perl

Imagine I have a CPAN-ish module I can't allow myself to modify directly
Module::Cool which has the methods new, communicate_heartbeat, is_running, remove_heartbeat and prefix.

I want to use these methods, but I need to change "prefix" method a bit.
I heard that you can create in your local, server, etc, a file like:

```
package My::Module::Cool;               

use strict;                              
use warnings;                            
use utf8;                                

use parent qw(Module::Cool);                                                                                                        

1;
```

If I add a "sub prefix{ ....}" method here, when I try to use My::Module::Cool, which "prefix" method will prevail, the new one I wrote or the original coming from the parent module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those methods are functions (note: NOT part of a class, not something you've done `my $instance = Module::Cool->new();` it won't do quite what you want.  Subroutines exported by the parent module into your module won't be imported to your namespace (intentionally - it would break OO) with the `use parent` call since the 'parent' module is for extending objects only.  If those are subroutines that just happen to have OO like names, `Exporter` (the module used for exporting functions) can do the trick.

First you have to bring the other functions you want into your module (with an import -- this is what `use Cool::Module` does behind the scenes anyway when it exports subroutines), build your own replacement function (invoking the original if needed), and exporting everything again.

Here's an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

# Make sure this happens at compile time, before anything else in the module
BEGIN {
    require Module::Cool; # make sure it loads, but don't import yet

    # get all the functions you want to normally import
    my @imports = grep { $_ ne 'prefix' } @Module::Cool::EXPORT;

    # Now do the actual import after filtering; see `perldoc use`.
    Module::Cool->import(@imports); 
};

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw/Exporter/; # The 'Exporter' base class does function exporting
our @EXPORT = @Module::Cool::EXPORT; # same export list

sub prefix
{
    my @args = @_;

    # stuff before calling the original prefix

    Module::Cool::prefix(@_);

    # then do stuff after

    return ...; # and return as before.
}

1;
```

If `Cool::Module` doesn't auto-export, swap to `@EXPORT_OK`, and use the `@EXPORT_OK` list.  See [`perldoc Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. See: [perlobj](http://ggperldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Inheritance)

From perlobj:

```
Method Resolution Order

Method resolution order only matters in the case of multiple inheritance. 
In the case of single inheritance, Perl simply looks up the inheritance 
chain to find a method:

    Grandparent
     |
    Parent
     |
    Child
```

Answer (score 2):

If those methods are part of a class, it'll work fine! :-)

```
PS C:\dev> perl
package My::Base;

use 5.012;
use warnings;

sub new { return bless {}, shift; }
sub frob { say "in base" }

package My::Child;

use 5.012;
use warnings;

use base 'My::Base';

sub frob { say "in child"; }

package main;

my $base = My::Base->new();
$base->frob();

my $child = My::Child->new();
$child->frob();
```

Gives:

```
in base
in child
PS C:\dev>
```

To call the parent function, use the special `SUPER` prefix.  Modifying the example above to:

```
# in My::Child...   
sub frob {
    my $self = shift; 
    $self->SUPER::frob(); 
    say "in child"; 
}
```

gives...

```
in base
in base
in child
```

And now both the parent and the child are called when child's method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example if `Module::Cool` is `OO`.

Parent Class

```
package TestPackage;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
sub prefix {
    my $self = shift;

    return "TestPackage";
}

sub is_running {
    my $self = shift;

    return "duh";
}

1;
```

Child

```
package TestPackage2;

use warnings; 
use strict;

use base 'TestPackage';

sub prefix {
    my $self = shift;

    return "TestPackage2";
}

1;
```

some script using child class

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

use TestPackage2;

my $tp2 = TestPackage2->new();

print $tp2->prefix(), "\n";
print $tp2->is_running(), "\n";
```

OUTPUT

```
$ test.pl
TestPackage2
duh
```